# Is it possible to access/display a cancel button on a mobile keyboard?

Tags: forms, vue.js, mobile, single-page-application

I'm hoping to remove some buttons from the UI in the mobile version of my Vue-built SPA.

If I include a form element in my app, the return button on a mobile keyboard allows the form to be submitted, and thus trigger all of the related listeners that close the form, update the data, etc.

Is there a way to access a cancel button for forms on mobile keyboards?

Answer (score -1):

There is no way of triggering a forms "reset" button via a mobile keyboard.
Cheers